# How this TS type is found (example with React and final-form)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand how a type is computed in this exemple (this is React with the final form npm, if this is related to them) :

This is my snippet ([test it on TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdwAdjFlAXlnAGLBYA2AEwCSTMAFcYABWJhUAHl4DBANWT9xWADRwAKnCwAPVk0HoAEroCyAGQCi-LCCwsAfHADedOHCbJnAFxwqDBQzADm9D4QTABCGlBBABRYAG4uMAD8Qdh4MAB03BC44qh26Szyuq4AlHAAvO6pEMCCUXAxAMIAFshM4VjJaRk5VAU9fQPlGVXuAD4oTACedY1wza3tMUUlqEMVWaN5hcWl05XVq00tbd5wMEtgWNnBoRHtqeqaQUpCahpYdq4bpYXAAaywgheACMIBBHH12iBxPwYMAwI4YXCEUx6ABfBhGSCwODMVjsTg8PhCbCmNgyCByRTU1RfbR6AzGFxmOCWWwOJwZdxeHzMCQwH4s0TihlM36sgE6ar4hhktgcXBcWXoEVwAgsyXKWmCemyBQhML9HR8mzSyQC5xuJFoMEvABETHEIGhbDdcAWbqeUE1LD9C3EdP1TEh7RCS0xQT6SxVdAIEfwwBicE6An4dpgSV1%20uUQV1orEklL6zZOi6vX67PyTbFkm1cDxOgA9J24AzoY5SCDKB0mPcQaSK9IzfdHlg7h27iAXVo7nHHCu8UFtXUvHcfLgYiERztSg0JzKzfltqdUAwfD5u3AAOrdJbHm-BYDhPwwcTD4DoEE167PsGQvLk%20AnLs5wwPINr5g6GQ6Ihbj%20nAEYmlGkJXOsNz0HucCPi%20yDwMInJPPgcBAUwJ57HAKQHOBYxQWcByzDhGy3HQeJAA)):

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface FieldInputProps<FieldValue, T extends HTMLElement> {
  name: string;
  onBlur: (event?: React.FocusEvent<T>) => void;
  onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<T> | any) => void;
  onFocus: (event?: React.FocusEvent<T>) => void;
  type?: string;
  value: FieldValue;
  checked?: boolean;
  multiple?: boolean;
}

export interface FieldRenderProps<FieldValue, T extends HTMLElement> {
  input: FieldInputProps<FieldValue, T>;
}

interface Props {
  field: FieldRenderProps<string, HTMLInputElement>;
  mask?: "number" | "percent" | undefined;
  style?: any;
}

function CellInput({
  field: {
    input: { value, onChange, ...inputProps }, // Problem here on the inputProps type
  },
  mask,
  style,
}: Props) {

    const onFocus = inputProps.onFocus

    // Why onFocus signature is : onFocus: (event?: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement, Element> | undefined) => void;

    // What I expect : onFocus: (event?: React.FocusEvent<T>) => void;

}
```

I don't understand why my variable inputProps has this signature for onFocus :

It is `onFocus: (event?: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement, Element> | undefined) => void;`.

What I expect is : `onFocus: (event?: React.FocusEvent<T>) => void;`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is bound to React type FocusEvent :

Before, in my app, I used `@types/react": "16.9.25",` which has :

```
interface FocusEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T, NativeFocusEvent> {
    relatedTarget: EventTarget | null;
    target: EventTarget & T;
}
```

Now, in `"@types/react": "^17.0.28"`, the interface takes 2 generics, both of them are optionnal and have Element type as default.

```
interface FocusEvent<Target = Element, RelatedTarget = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<Target, NativeFocusEvent> {
    relatedTarget: (EventTarget & RelatedTarget) | null;
    target: EventTarget & Target;
}
```

So in my code, as there is no second generic transmitted, the resulting type is :

```
React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement, Element> | undefined) => void;
```